# How do I remove the scrollbars / border in a layer window?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to get my workspace to look like this: http://youtu.be/mFRHTs8-KVw?t=1m14s

See how the layer window has no scroll bars / title?

How do I achieve the same? That is a tutorial video and when he pans it works differently than my Photoshop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>F</kbd> to ***[Toggle Screen Modes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSD578BD7D-07BC-46f6-AAC2-6E491E8AD818a.html#WS68AAA309-D527-44b3-8A95-FEDC2CB851BFa)***:

> Toggle (forward) between Standard screen mode, Full screen mode with menu bar, and Full screen mode

This is also accessible through the <kbd>View → Screen mode → ...</kbd> menu